# average of a bounded convex set

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a bounded convex set. We know that the average of any $n$ points of $X$, belongs to it, i.e. if  $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n \in X$ then $\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n}\in X$.
How can we define the average of all elements of $X$?

Comment: Compute the centroid.

Comment: If $X\subseteq R^n$ you are right. But $X$ is a bounded convex set in an arbitrary normed space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

There is no natural definition of an average for each bounded convex  subset $X$ in an arbitrary normed space.
Let $X$ be the convex hull of the set of standard orts of the space $\ell^2$. Suppose that $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n,\dots)$ is an average of the set $X$. Since for any permutation $\sigma$ of the set $\mathbb N$ the respective linear transformation $\hat\sigma$ of the space $\ell^2$,
defined as $\hat\sigma(x)_i=x_{\sigma(i)}$ for each $x\in\ell_2$ and each $i\in\mathbb N$,
induces a linear bijection on the set $X$. Therefore it is natural to expect that $\hat\sigma(a)=a$. 
But since $a\in\ell^2$  then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. So $a=0$. But $0\not\in X$.